# ElasticSearch HTTP client vs Transport client

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the best practice using ElasticSearch from Java?
For instance one can easily find documentation and examples for delete-by-query functionality using [REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/delete-by-query-usage.html).
This is not the case for Java Transport Client.

1. Where can I find usage examples for Java Transport Client ?
2. Does Java Transport Client cover whole ElasticSearch functionality like HTTP client via REST API?

Answer (score 5):

The best practice of using Elasticsearch from Java: [Follow This](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/What-is-your-best-practice-to-access-a-cluster-by-a-Java-client-td4015311.html)

Nexts:

1. You can follow the library : [JEST](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest)
2. Yes, in maximum time, Java Transport Client cover whole ElasticSearch functionality like HTTP client via REST API

Answer (score 0):

To complete [@sunkuet02 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526315/elasticsearch-http-client-vs-transport-client/37526762#37526762):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-interfacing-elasticsearch-picking-client), the `TransportClient` is the preferred way if you're using java (performance, serialization, ...).
But the jar is quite heavy (with dependencies) and it requires that you use the same versions between client and server to work.

If you want a very lightweight client, there is a new [Java REST client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html) in Elastic 5.x.
I don't know the differences with Jest, but it's compatible with last Elastic 5.x versions (but not with previous versions) and it's developed by the Elastic team.
So it might be a good option to consider, according to your needs.